# All indexing are stuck at `processing`

Tags: admin, ce-1.7.0.2, reindex

I am using CE 1.7.0.2 all indexes stuck at processing since 24 hours. When try to do indexing manually throw an error:

> xxx Index process is working now. Please try run this process later

As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127430/magento-indexes-issue-cant-reindex 
I always use SSH to do indexing. I deleted all files under `\var\locks`, DIR permission is `777` But when tried indexing one by one then throws same error and locks files regenerate again.

Please tell how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento Category Products reindex error - Integrity constraint violation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63815/magento-category-products-reindex-error-integrity-constraint-violation)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by executing the following steps:

**1. Recreate each index individually executing shell commands:**

```
php shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_attribute

php shell/indexer.php -reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

php shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_category_flat

php shell/indexer.php -reindex cataloginventory_stock

php shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_category_product

php shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_price

php shell/indexer.php -reindex tag_summary

php shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_url
```

**2. Clear all files inside of var/locks/ directory**

**3. Apply 777 permission to var/locks/**

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue at my end successfully :)

1. First you delete locks folder under var directory: `var/locks`
2. make sure 777 permission is `var/locks` and all files under locks
   directory.
3. Take a backup of your database & delete `catalog_product_flat_1`,
   `catalog_product_flat_2` or if there is another one.
4. execute following code:

```
php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

This will reindex your Catalog Search Index or if you want to update all of the indexes run:

```
php indexer.php reindexall
```

Answer (score -1):

Do following steps to fix this error.

1. Clear your database logs, you can find mysql query in below link
   https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-perform-magento-database-maintenance.html
2. Take a backup of your database & delete catalog_product_flat_1, catalog_product_flat_2 or if there is another one with name catalog_product_flat_2, You need this step if you are using flat catalog options enabled.
3. Run one by one indexer through SSH commands

   ```
   php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_attribute
   php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
   php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_category_flat
   php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex cataloginventory_stock
   php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_category_product
   php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_product_price
   php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex tag_summary
   php ./shell/indexer.php -reindex catalog_url
   ```

Comment: Its seems risky to me. As I already deleted all log from database, but still all indexes are in `processing` status. If I delete `catalog_product_flat_1` and even after that if re-indexing (using SSH) throw an error then it will be trouble. Will you tell how I can find, why indexing always in `processing` status?

Comment: send me cPanel or FTP/magentoadmin/phpmyadmin access to look into your issue. Skype: amalik62

Comment: Also please provide me more information, what all the indexes are in `processing` or some of them.

Comment: you can delete all the files in var/locks folder and change the permission to 777 for that folder. after that perform reindex by SSH

Comment: All indexes are in `processing` state. I already deleted var/locks files and dir permission to 777

Comment: Please don't send this guy your hosting credentials.

Comment: This answer adds no value to the existing answer